# Using the Msp430fr5969 to send strings over Tx

Tags: c, embedded, msp430

I am trying to send data from the Msp430fr5969 Launchpad to the rn-52-ek so it can pass the data along through bluetooth.

```
#include <msp430.h> 

void uartSend(unsigned char *pucData, unsigned char ucLength)
{
  while(ucLength>0)
  {

    // Wait for TX buffer to be ready for new data
    while(!(UCA1IFG & UCTXIFG));

    // Push data to TX buffer
    UCA1TXBUF = *pucData;

    // Update variables
    ucLength--;
    pucData++;
  }



}
void initUART()
{

     /* Place UCA0 in Reset to be configured */
      UCA0CTL1 = UCSWRST;

      //Set BRCLK = SMCLK
      UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL_2;

      //Values found using table for 16Mhz and 115200 baudrate
      UCA0BR0=8;
      UCA0BR1=0;
      UCA0MCTLW = 0xF7 << 8;
      UCA0MCTLW |= 10 << 4;
      UCA0MCTLW |= UCOS16;

      //UCA0 out of reset
      UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;
}

int main(void) {
      // disable watchdog timer
      //------------------------
      WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;               // Stop WDT

      initUART();


      unsigned char sendString[] = "Banana";
      unsigned char length=6;
      while(1)
      {


          uartSend(sendString,length);

      }

      return 0;
}
```

Nothing is happening when I run the above code, not even reading anything on the multimeter. What am I missing?

I know there are some bad practices, I just want to get it working and I'll add the interrupt based sending later.

Comment: A multimeter is a poor tool for debugging a time domain signal.  Even an LED might be better, but what you really want is a scope.  Have you configured whatever pin is involved to be an output driven by the UART block, and not say a GPIO input (the likely power-on default)?  If you can find some known-good code that might be a good idea to try too, for comparison.

Comment: I know about the multimeter, I was just trying to see if there was any difference between the program running and not running(there wasn't) and it was my best option available.

With regards to the good code, unfortunately the specific chip we're using doesn't have a lot of examples online. This is mostly me trying to port code from other versions of the msp430

Comment: I have no idea, because I'm running into something very similar myself; but I do notice that you don't seem to be setting up your clocks --- are you sure you're running at 16MHz?

Answer (score 0):

You should set Port 2.5 as Tx for the UART